Apex Chart React show tooltip for all charts when hovering one of them
I have multiple charts and expected that hover to 1 data point on this chart will auto show the tooltip on another chart and vice versa.
Basically, I don't find any apex chart api that allow to control the tooltip.
The expectation is shown in the image below:


Does this Apexcharts documentation answer your question? https://apexcharts.com/docs/chart-types/synchronized-charts/
